# node.js, socket.io movement

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am creating a 4 player game using node.js and socket.io. In my game each player has its coordinates everything is good apart from movement. I have trouble in moving my characters. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I will be grateful for any help.

**Server Side:**

```
    socket.on('move', function(data)
                     {
                         var w = data["dir"];
                         var x = data["x"];
                         var y = data["y"];

                                if(w == "down")
                                    y += 5;

                                if(w == "up")
                                    y -= 5;

                                if(w == "left")
                                    x -= 5;

                                if(w == "right")
                                    x += 5;

                                console.log(y);

                                io.sockets.emit("_movement",{ "X" : x, "Y" : y});


                     });
```

**Client Side:**

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", movement);   

function movement(evt)
        {
            switch(evt.keyCode)
            {
                case 40:    
                            socket.emit("move", {"y" : socketPlayer1.playerImage.y, "dir" : "down"});
                            break;
                case 38:    
                            socket.emit("move", {"y" : socketPlayer1.playerImage.y, "dir" : "up"});
                            break;
                case 37:    
                            socket.emit("move", {"x" : socketPlayer1.playerImage.x, "dir": "left" });
                            break;
                case 39:     
                            socket.emit("move", {"x" : socketPlayer1.playerImage.x, "dir": "right" });
                            break;
            }
        }           
        }       
  socket.on("_movement", function(data)
        {
            socketPlayer1.x = data["X"];
            socketPlayer1.y = data["Y"];
        });
```

Thanks for attention.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Characters don't move. As I mentioned before

Comment: Can you print x and y's values on server side ?

Comment: Does the movement function fire? Is this full source from your source?

Comment: @MukeshSharma, when I press left  and up arrows it prints 695 and undefined, and when I press right and down arrows it prints 705 and undefinend.

Comment: @bolav, no this isn't the full code, if it is necessary I can show the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is bug in you code

Whenever there is left/right key press, you send `x` value. But on server, you read both `x` and `y`, where `y` is undefined and then you send back those values to client where your existing x and y got updated. Since y is undefined, there is not movement.

Similarly for up/down key press.

**Solution**:

**Improved Client Side**: Send both x and y coordinates.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", movement);   

function movement(evt)
{
   var dir ="nowhere";
   switch(evt.keyCode)
   {
      case 40:    
         dir = "down";
         break;
      case 38: 
         dir = "up";
         break;
      case 37:    
         dir = "left";
         break;
      case 39:     
         dir = "right";
         break;
    }
    socket.emit("move", {"x" : socketPlayer1.playerImage.x, "y" : socketPlayer1.playerImage.y, "dir": dir });         
 }     

 socket.on("_movement", function(data)
 {
     socketPlayer1.x = data["X"];
     socketPlayer1.y = data["Y"];
 });
```

Disclaimer: There can be typos.

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- The javascript you pasted does not compile, because of double `}` when ending `function movement`.
- You are sending data from `socketPlayer1.playerImage.x` and reading back to `socketPlayer1.x`
- The client is just sending `x` on left/right, but the server sends both `x`and `y` back, and the client sets both values.

Try sending both `x` and `y` on all movement.